# Making my own API, confused on how to authenticate with server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to make a Discord bot that retrieves a player's stats from the Ubisoft Rainbow Six stat website. I've worked with APIs before and I know the basics of Node and making GET requests to certain URLs. I monitored the network activity for a player's profile and found the specific URL that I need to perform a request on but I get a `HTTP 400 error`. I'm assuming this is because I've never authenticated with the server who I am. So I read up on authentication and the like and figured that all I had to do was include in the request header my username and password for the website(at this point I should mention that the site makes you login to retrieve player's stats). I went on Postman and included my username/password for Basic Auth and OAuth2 and I still get a `HTTP 400 error`, so there's obviously got to be more that I'm missing. It seems that in the network activity that some of the requests include a token, which I'm assuming is some sort of session token. I'm just completely confused as to what I'm supposed to do, as I'm kind of diving head first into this but I would really appreciate it if someone could provide some resources where I could try to fill in the gaps or help me resolve the issue. Code at the moment using pure JS/Node:

```
//import
const https = require('https');
const http = require('http');

//https://public-ubiservices.ubi.com/v3/profiles?namesOnPlatform=pope&platformType=uplay
var username = '';
var password = '';
var req_username = '';


//get session_id
function get_session_id(username, password) {
    const options = {
        host: 'public-ubiservices.ubi.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/v3/profiles/sessions',
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64'),
            'Ubi-AppId': '',
        }
    }
    const req_session_id = https.request(options, res => {
        let res_body = '';
        res.on('data', data => {
            res_body += data;
        })
        
        res.on('end', () => {
            res_body = JSON.parse(res_body);
            console.log(res_body);
        })  
    });
   req_session_id.end();
}
//retrieve player stats
function get_stats(req_username) {
    const options = {
        host: 'public-ubiservices.ubi.com',
        port: 443,
        path: `/v3/profiles?namesOnPlatform=${req_username}&platformType=uplay`,
        method: 'GET',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Basic' + Buffer.from(username + ':' + password).toString('base64'),
            'Ubi-AppId': '',
        }
    }

    const req_get_stats = https.request(options, res => {
    let res_body = '';
    res.on('data', data => {
        res_body += data;
    });

    res.on('end', () => {
        res_body = JSON.parse(res_body);
        console.log(res_body);
       });
   });
   req_get_stats.end();
}

get_session_id(username, password);
get_stats(req_username);
```

Comment: Please read the documentation of the packages/framework you are using, mention their names, and mention the code you have written. If you are using vanilla Node.js you must provide code snippets regarding the same.

Comment: goto the url.. your see `{"message":" The Ubi-AppId header is missing","errorCode":1,"httpCode":400,...` your need to read the docs on the api your using

Comment: I'm making my own API. Right now, I'm only using pure Node.

Comment: You will need to make a request to login which should return you the token you need to retrieve the data you want. Some APIs will not fulfill requests made by other sites so you may still fail.

Comment: @RichardHubley Yes, I actually deduced that as well and implemented that sort of. I did a POST request to the login page but it's not returning me any response at the moment. Trying to figure it out but I'll keep posted. I appreciate the reply.

Comment: using the network panel in Chrome Dev Tools is a great way to see how their site does the login.

Comment: Finally found the Ubi-App ID by taking your advice and specifically looking at the login page's network activity. Now I just have to figure out how to extract that from the POST request and then connect that with my GET requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/r6api.js

heres an example:

```
const R6API = require('r6api.js');
const r6api = new R6API('email', 'password');

const username = 'Daniel.Nt'
const platform = 'uplay';

const id = await r6api.getId(platform, username).then(el => el[0].userId);
const stats = await r6api.getStats(platform, id).then(el => el[0]);

console.log(`${username} has played ${stats.pvp.general.matches} matches.`);
```

Comment: Hey I appreciate it. I know I could have done that but I'm specifically trying to make my own api so I can learn :)

Comment: oh ok, in that case check out the github repository of that package, more specifically the requests they are sending:
https://github.com/danielwerg/r6api.js/blob/master/lib/methods
https://github.com/danielwerg/r6api.js

Comment: I may do that and it crossed my mind, but I'm trying to figure it out myself first before I look at the page because I don't want to be dependent on it and I want my learning to be as natural as possible :P